# GCD->blocks->C++->SQLCipher: Sqlite3MemMalloc memory does not release after task completion

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

I am working on database application and using SQLCipher for database encryption. I am using GCD serial queue for all database related operation and manual memory management. Below is code snippet for my database related operations. I have more methods like `saveRecordData:` which calls the `executeOnGCD:` for different types of records.

```
-(void)saveRecordData:(NSArray *)dataObjects{
    [self executeOnGCD:^{
        std::vector<RecordData> list;

        for(id object in dataObjects){
            RecordData recordDataObject(/*create c++ data object*/)
            list.push_back(recordDataObject);
        }

        DataBaseManager::GetInstance()->saveData(list);
    }];
}

-(void)executeOnGCD:(void (^)())block{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    task = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:task];
        task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    void (^executionBlock)() = ^(){
        @autoreleasepool {
            block();
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:task];
            task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    };
    //dataManagerQueue is serial queue.
    dispatch_async(self.dataManagerQueue, executionBlock);
}
```

Here DataBaseManager is C++ class which performs actual database insert. DataBaseManager's saveData implementation is as below.

```
void saveData(std::vector<RecordData> list) {
    for(RecordData record : list)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt * statement = nullptr;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_dbConnection, INSERT_STATEMENT, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //Bind parameters
            int index = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(statement, COLUMN1);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, index, value1);

            index = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(statement, COLUMN2);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, index, value2);

            /*Bind other parameters*/

            sqlite3_step(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
}
```

When my application saves 80k+ records using saveData function, there is  memory allocation difference between when the operation started and when operation ended. Instruments suggest there is still memory allocated by SQLCipher which is not released even after the 5 mins of operation completion. As shown in below image at the start of the operation memory allocation was 1.90mb and after completion of task memory reduces to 6.6mb not to 1.90mb

[image]

Also once the operation completed, memory reduce very slowly and takes around 6 mins to reduce memory from 20mb to 6.6mb.

my questions are

1)why memory did not drop to ~1.90mb after completion of task? Is this something related to using c++ objects in GCD?

2) Why it takes ~6min to reduce memory from 20mb to 6.6mb? Does GCD release memory slowly?

3) I also see `_dispatch_alloc_try_create_heap` block allocated by libdispatch.dylb, which is also not released after operation completion.

4) Am I using right approach for nested blocks in `executeOnGCD:` method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to the situation you have, but I have some suggestions, and they were more than would fit in a comment...

What you want to do here is to look at the stack traces of the free events that are happening over the 6 minutes after completion. That should give you some clues as to how the deallocations are being scheduled. It seems likely that there's some background thread doing cleanup. Getting those stack traces should allow you to search the code for where that cleanup is originally scheduled, and that should provide the answers you seek.

The close similarity between the upward and downward slopes of that graph makes *me* think that (conceptually) a timer is started when the object is last used, and that there's some mechanism that reaps them after some period of inactivity. This is probably implemented by registering the objects with some registry at malloc time, then updating a `lastUsed` field on every usage of the object, and then a periodic process walks the list and says, effectively, "free all objects that haven't been used for X amount of time." This might exist to provide some kind of implicit caching mechanism.

I don't know any of this for sure, but it seems like a probable explanation.